# Upload a file From android using WCF service and Ksoap2

Tags: android, wcf, file, upload

I have developed a WCF Service .NET4 (SOAP) and I am trying to consume it from Android.
But the problem that i get this error:

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException:
>   expected: END_TAG
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body
>   (position:END_TAG
>   @1:761
>   in java.io.InputStreamReader@437c3ff0)

in this line:

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

Here is my code:

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/OCRWebService/extractText";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "extractText";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/ocrwebservice/Service.svc";
private String extractText(byte[] _data){
     try {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo p1=new PropertyInfo();
            p1.setName("image2up");
            p1.setType(_data);
            request.addProperty(p1);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);  // error here
            SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
            String resultData=result.getProperty(0).toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.i("123",e.getMessage());
            }
    return "false";
```

}

(For information: I want to upload a file from android device to my server using wcf servcice)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing to upload an image to the server..But I am getting Serialization exception not parser exception. I mentioned the method name in the url also.May be your problem is that...I am not sure.....

Answer (score 0):

```
public void testWebService(Bitmap bmp)
{
    MarshalBase64 marshal = new MarshalBase64();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    byte[] raw = out.toByteArray();
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);
    request.addProperty("image", raw);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    marshal.register(envelope);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
    try
    {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Object response = envelope.getResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Try to implements it ..

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused by SOAP_ACTION:

in SOAP action u specify : http://packagename/method that u call

So modify your SOAP action to this:
final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/extractText";
final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

and if doesn't work try with this:

final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/extractText";
final String NAMESPACE = "http://org.tempury/";

Hope it helps!
Mike!